# Erro no envio de email

Tags: delphi, email, delphi-2010

Tenho uma aplicação em `Delphi 2010` que enviava `emails` normalmente pelos componentes `INDY`. De um tempo para cá não consigo mais enviar `emails`.
Já alterei as definições na minha conta `GMAIL` para:

> permitir aplicativos menos seguros

Mas mesmo assim não consigo. Alguém tem alguma informação que possa ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: Olá Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, poste o seu código para o pessoal providenciar a ajuda mais facilmente, ok?

Comment: Dê uma resumida na sua função que faz o envio e coloque aqui para tentarmos localizar o problema. Só fazendo esse resumo talvez já encontre o problema você mesmo...